How can I enable Auto fitting of column widths in the python package openpyxl?
This is a similar question to Openpyxl autosize column size -and- python openpyxl worksheet autosizing column_dimensions - fail -and- How to set column width to bestFit in openpyxl
Has anyone found out how to fit column widths of Excel worksheets using the openpyxl package as of 2024? The ColumnDimension object, which defines the auto_size and best_fit property, does nothing for me.
Here is what I got so far - I spare you the text extent calculations from 3rd-party GUI frameworks:
ws = Workbook.active # loaded workbook, first sheet

# some column width change, most do not, none are fit correctly
ws.column_dimensions["A"].auto_size = True

# the width can be set manually.
# I think width is specified in millimeters
ws.column_dimensions["A"].with = 123

My only strategies at this point are:

calculate the text extent, set width manually. Unfortunately, I have not found a GetTextExtent() method in openpyxl. I patched wx.ScreenDC.GetTextExtent with set Font (calibri, size 11) from wxPython in - but the calculation does not match either. It did not help that I had to convert pixels to millimeters. How else could I calculate the required width in millimeter from a text string?
Use the VBA-Method Range.AutoFit. Does openpyxl have a "Range" object comparable to or directly invoking the Range-interface? I have search the docu but found only iterable cell-"range"-generators.
Ask the developers / volunteers of openpyxl to explain possible approaches to auto fit columns widths, or hope that one of the reads my question here.


Autofit in Excel is something that the Excel app does. The Xlsxwriter autofit is a calculation based on cell contents and that's still what you are obliged to do where Excel app is not used as in Openpyxl.
